# Debug console in PyDev with AppEngine development server

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am trying to debug a Google AppEngine project in Eclipse/PyDev running on Ubuntu.

Debugging generally works fine, but I am not able to evaluate expressions in the debug console.  I believe the console is starting the AppEngine server and is pausing waiting for the AppEngine development server to end so I am not able to get the evaluation prompt.

This is the output in the debug console:

```
pydev debugger: warning: psyco not available for speedups (the debugger will still work correctly, but a bit slower)
pydev debugger: starting
/home/eric/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py:42: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  import sha
/home/eric/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_login.py:33: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
INFO     2010-11-02 22:00:13,657 appengine_rpc.py:153] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2010-11-02 22:00:13,679 appcfg.py:414] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2010-11-02 22:00:14,010 appcfg.py:428] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2010-11-02 22:00:14,011 datastore_file_stub.py:818] Could not read datastore data from /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore
INFO     2010-11-02 22:00:14,080 dev_appserver_main.py:443] Running application manualent on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
```

Notice that it never prints a prompt at the end of the console for entering expressions to be evaluated.

Any idea how to get the prompt to properly come up so that I can evaluate expressions during debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the AppEngine interactive console that's part of your application instead?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#The_Development_Console

The server is currently using the Python interpreter which is why you never get a prompt (because it's just a single interpreter, and it's already in use); if you're wanting to run Python expressions within the context of the server, the development console is what you'll want to use.

There's also a more "console-like" version of the interactive Python session available from third-party developers: http://con.appspot.com/console/help/about

Answer (score 0):

Try using the remote debugging capability - I run into potentially similar issue on Apache + mod_wsgi and resolved it by setting `stdoutToServer=True` and `sterrToServer=True` to route output to the PyDev remote debugger:

```
from pydevsrc import pydevd;pydevd.settrace('192.168.2.8', stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```